Organizing EF Core model data separate from Business model data
What is the best practice for keeping the EF Core model separate from business logic that would naturally go in the model?
For example, I have an Area that has some data points that should persist (name, ID) and and some that are transient (players, items, maybe a spell effect on the area like fire storm that should not be saved in the database)? Do I want a separate model?
class AreaRecord {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

class Area {
    public AreaRecord AreaRecord { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Player> Players { get; } = new List<Player>();
    public ICollection<Effect> Effects { get; } = new List<Effect>();
    public string GetExample() { return AreaRecord.Name + " has " + Players.Count; }
}

Don't mind the uselessness of GetExample() my point is just that the Area class would have business logic and temporary data. For example, I do not want to persist the Players list because if the game restarts, there should be no players in the area.
This is multiplied by many (ItemRecord/Item, PlayerRecord/Player, AreaRecord/Area, RoomRecord/Room) and so forth. Is this the right approach? What keywords or topics should I read up on to understand whether this is the right approach or find a better approach?
What I think I understand so far is that EF Core models shouldn't have business logic because of the limitations where you can't have public setters for data that shouldn't be persisted. And I worry about accidentally adding a new database column if I used the Area as the business logic model.
I think part of my issue is searching for the right terminology to even research or ask my question.

If AreaRecord is your entity model, then just make a DTO object from that and include the properties/accessors you don't want in your entity model. If your accessors require an injection, I'd rethink your strategy. Try keeping it simple and dependent on the internal properties only.

I recommend using contracts for your DTOs. You can find a sample on this repository: https://github.com/kyree-henry/HealthInsurePro. Additionally, consider using the AutoMapper package and its ProjectTo extension method. Feel free to explore the repository and select what you need, if any.

Edit:
I did a bit more reading, and found this. I would agree with what he says:
article

I would look here. You can specifically exclude properties on your models.
Entity Properties
Included and excluded properties
By convention, all public properties with a getter and a setter will be included in the model.
Specific properties can be excluded as follows:
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public DateTime LoadedFromDatabase { get; set; }
}

Or you could do it in the model builder:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
        .Ignore(b => b.LoadedFromDatabase);
}


Thanks for the update, David. I think that addresses what I was looking for. Especially: "For one, your persistence logic and business/domain logic should be separated layers. Since the EF entity belongs to the persistance layer, and validation (or general operations) belong to the business/domain layer, these logically shouldn't find themselves in the same class definition."
